# Best way to check broken links and unused files for HTML site

Tags: file-management, html

I am looking for the best way to check for unused image files, unused javascript files, and broken links within an HTML site. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is probably off topic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3 offers an online tool to check for broken links here: http://validator.w3.org/checklink. If by unused files you mean files that are not linked to by the website, you can't check for files that are on a server that are not linked to. It is generally not possible to request a directory's contents from a webserver so there's no way to check for unused files in that respect.